# Filtering data template objects in Hugo

Tags: json, hugo, data-files

So I'm trying to build a quick page listing event details with Hugo (first time working with it, so bear with me).

I've put the two categories of events into two JSON files and added them to /data/events/aevents.json and /data/events/bevents.json

Sample json

```
{
"devcon 1": {"evname": "Dev Con 1", "year": "2019", "date": "2020-05-12T23:29:49Z"}, 
"devcon2": {"evname": "Dev Con 1", "year": "2018", "date": "2018-05-12T23:29:49Z"}
}
```

Now when I use

```
{{ range .Site.Data.events.aevents }}
```

things work as expected.But they don't when I use

```
{{ range .Site.Data.events }}
```

which I thought would give me events from aevents.json and bevents.json.

**Second part**

The json events have a date property. When I try to filter to just show upcoming events, my list is blank. I've been playing with variants of this:

```
{{ range where .Site.Data.events.aevents "date" "ge" now }}
```

and have tried a bunch of different date formats. Any tips on where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Part**

The snippet:

```
{{ range .Site.Data.events }}
```

Will get you two objects - one for aevents and one for bevents. You will need to do a nested `range` to process the individual events in the two files.

```
{{ range .Site.Data.events }}
    {{ range . }}
       .....
```

**Second Part**

I don't think that can be done directly in the range so you will need to filter afterwards:

```
{{ range .Site.Data.events }}
  {{ range . }}
    {{ if .date > $date }}
      ...
```